# Four cards are selected from a deck of 52 cards. Calculate the probability that no two cards have the same value.

Tags: probability

> Four cards are selected from a pack of 52 cards. Calculate the probability that no two cards have the same value.

**My attempt**: Paying cards have 13 possible values $2,3,4 ... , 9, 10, J, Q, K, Ace.$ We first choose 4 values then we choose one card for each of the values.

Hence, probability equals $\frac{{13 \choose 4} 4^4}{{52 \choose 4}}= 0.676$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simpler to think that the order of drawing cards matters (it does affect the final probability). Then the total number of ways to draw $4$ cards is

$$52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49$$

and the number of ways to draw 4 cards of different value is

$$52 \cdot 48 \cdot 44 \cdot 40$$

so the probability is

$$\frac{48 \cdot 44 \cdot 40}{51\cdot 50\cdot 49}\approx 0.676$$