# On the probability of no two cards with the same face value

Tags: probability, combinatorics, problem-solving, card-games

An experiment consists of drawing 10 cards from an ordinary 52-card pack. If the drawing is done **with replacement**, find the probability that no two cards will have the same face
value.

The solution to this almost trivial if we work with ordered samples. Indeed, there are 13 ways to select the first kind, and 4 ways to select a suit for that kind. Next, for the second card there are 12 kinds left and again 4 ways so select a suit. There are

$$(13\cdot 4)(12\cdot 4)\cdots(4\cdot 4) = 52\cdot48\cdots 20\cdot 16$$

ways to generating hands of 10 cards in which the **order counts** and the kids are all different. The fact that that sampling is with replacement has no importance at this point since we are not allowed to have duplications in terms of face values anyway. For the denominator, we note that there are obiously

$$52^{10}$$ ways to generate hands of 10 cards where the order counts **with replacement**. So the required probability is

$$
p = \frac{52\cdot48\cdots 20\cdot 16}{52^{10}}. 
$$
See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3680361/four-cards-are-selected-from-a-deck-of-52-cards-calculate-the-probability-that) for a similar problem.

Now the question: How would you go if you were forced to reason in terms of **unordered samples**? At present, I can only see that the denominator must be

$$
{52+10-1\choose 10},
$$
but I don't see a strategy for correctly computing the numerator...

Comment: Just to be clear, the order must matter when considering sampling with replacement. If you consider unordered hands equally likely, then it is no longer sampling with replacement. For instance, "getting the ace of spades ten times" is $1/10!$ as likely as "getting 1,2,...,10 of spades in some order" when sampling with replacement, but they are equally likely in your second formulation.

Comment: So going with unordered samples will destroy symmetry right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you found of $\dfrac{52\cdot 48\cdot 44\cdots 16}{52^{10}}$ is correct.  It could have been written more simply by not talking about all $52$ cards but rather talking about the $13$ ranks and ignoring suit.  It could also have been written more cleanly by using [the notation for falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) that $n\frac{k}{~} = \underbrace{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}_{k~\text{terms}}$ letting you write the answer as:

$$\dfrac{13\frac{10}{~}}{13^{10}}$$

As for unordered sampling... the punchline is going to be that whether you actually intentionally remember the order in which the sampling occurred or not it is more convenient to have pretended that you had kept track for the purposes of calculation.  The outcomes counted by stars and bars are *not* equally likely outcomes and so the denominator should *not* involve the calculation for $\binom{52+10-1}{10}$ regardless whether or not there exists a choice of sample space which could have been described as having that many elements.

Remember that the probability of an event $A$ from a sample space $S$ will equal $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{|A|}{|S|}$ when the outcomes in $S$ are known ahead of time to be equally likely events.  In general however you may *not* calculate $\Pr(A)$ in this fashion.  There are two outcomes to playing a lottery.  You win or you lose.  You do not win the lottery with probability $\dfrac{1}{2}$ however.

Comment: Yes, ingoring suit produces a shortcut, but still you are going with orderd samples. But my post is "what if you have to use only unorderd samples"? I guess it cannot be solved (if I intepreted correctly the comment above)

Comment: @utobi it can be solved and it is solved by *ignoring the fact the samples were recorded as unordered*.  Regardless whether the recording of the results of each outcome were ordered or unordered... the actual random process involved with having produced such a sample *was* ordered.  This is the case whether we were present in the room when such samples were being taken or not.  In order to work with a sample space that *is* equiprobable and allows us to use counting techniques, we simply remind ourselves of this fact and it allows us to proceed as normally.

Comment: @utobi it is the same principle as how when we have a bag of $99$ identical blue balls and one red ball and us pulling a ball out from the bag at random that we can still say that the probability of pulling the red ball is $\frac{1}{100}$ despite the fact that there are only two discernable outcomes.  To facilitate the calculations, we can *pretend* that each of the balls were uniquely labeled, thus allowing us to pretend there are $100$ different outcomes and then being able to use counting techniques to finish.

Comment: The same thing happens for example when rolling two dice.  Suppose I have a red die and a green die and I ask my colorblind friend to roll them.  He can't tell the difference between the dice apart and can only report to us one of the $21$ different possibilities he can discern... but if when I look I can tell all $36$ possibilities apart.  Do the dice know if they are being rolled by a colorblind person?  Of course not.  Do the laws of the universe suddenly change probabilities based on whether a colorblind person rolled the dice?  Of course not.

Comment: Colorblind or not, having both dice show a $1$ occurs with probability $\frac{1}{36}$.  In the same way, "*order-blind*" or not you will have all ranks different when taking such a sample you describe as being $\frac{13\frac{10}{~}}{13^{10}}$

Comment: My elaboration of all this: A probability equal to 1/21 for say (1,2) from the perspective of my colour-blind friend is fine as long as we are working within his probability model, uniform in the unordered samples. This is exactly the problem arising in my post. Probabilities calculated using unordered samples refer to a different model so will not, in general, be equal to those based on the ordered sample.

Comment: @utobi Are you saying that we win the lottery with probability $\frac{1}{2}$?  Are you saying that in a bag with $99$ blue balls and one red ball that the probability of pulling the red ball is $\frac{1}{2}$?  If so then you are not using the word "probability" correctly.

Comment: The point is that it is incorrect to assume that outcomes are equally likely.  Your "*different model*" was incorrect to use and does not accurately describe probabilities of the random processes described in your post.  Do there exist scenarios where there are $21$ equally likely outcomes?  Yes, of course... but not one that can describe the fair rolling of two dice and reading the results of them, colorblind or otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, I have to think about it...